How to make other citation fields besides year also clickable with biblatex+biber?
Consider the following MWE using biblatex+biber and hyperref
\documentclass{article}

% create Bibliografy.bib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliografy.bib}
@book{strangIntroductionLinearAlgebra1993,
title = {Introduction to Linear Algebra},
author = {Strang, Gilbert and Strang, Gilbert and Strang, Gilbert and Strang, Gilbert},
date = {1993},
volume = {3},
publisher = {Wellesley-Cambridge Press Wellesley, MA}
}
@inproceedings{fohlmeisterDualKalmanFiltering2018,
  title = {Dual {{Kalman}} Filtering Based {{GNSS}} Phase Tracking for Scintillation Mitigation},
  booktitle = {2018 {{IEEE}}/{{ION Position}}, {{Location}} and {{Navigation Symposium}} ({{PLANS}})},
  author = {Fohlmeister, Friederike and Antreich, Felix and Nossek, Josef A.},
  date = {2018-04},
  pages = {1151--1158},
  issn = {2153-3598},
  doi = {10.1109/PLANS.2018.8373499},
  eventtitle = {2018 {{IEEE}}/{{ION Position}}, {{Location}} and {{Navigation Symposium}} ({{PLANS}})},
  keywords = {GNSS,Synchronization}
}

@article{rinoAngleDependenceSingly1977,
  title = {The Angle Dependence of Singly Scattered Wavefields},
  author = {Rino, CL and Fremouw, EJ},
  date = {1977},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Atmospheric and Terrestrial Physics},
  shortjournal = {Journal of Atmospheric and Terrestrial Physics},
  volume = {39},
  number = {8},
  pages = {859--868},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  issn = {0021-9169}
}
\end{filecontents*}

% Use the biblatex package
\usepackage[style=authoryear, hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliografy.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

\title{My incredible title}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello world!

\begin{itemize}
    \item A normal citation: \cite{strangIntroductionLinearAlgebra1993}.
    \item A parenthesis citation: \parencite{fohlmeisterDualKalmanFiltering2018}. 
    \item A textual citation: \textcite{rinoAngleDependenceSingly1977}.
    \item Citing only the author's name: \citeauthor{strangIntroductionLinearAlgebra1993}.
    \item Citing only the year of publication: \citeyear{strangIntroductionLinearAlgebra1993}.
    \item Citing only the title of the source: \citetitle{rinoAngleDependenceSingly1977}.
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

By running

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error main.tex
biber main
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error main.tex
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error main.tex

it produces

This is pretty great as the year is clickable, but I want make other fields (author's name, title, etc) also clickable. How to do so?

Why use --shell-escape? You're using something insecure for no reason. (You may need it for other things in your document, but not this.)

@cfr yeah, whatever, I omitted it so...
